# Read in csv file from a website in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read in a csv file directly from a website. Below is the Python3 code:

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/pandas/plotting/alphabet_stock_data.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(url)
```

But I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [6], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 url = "https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/pandas/plotting/alphabet_stock_data.csv"
----> 3 data = pd.read_csv(url)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:311, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    305 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    306     warnings.warn(
    307         msg.format(arguments=arguments),
    308         FutureWarning,
    309         stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310     )
--> 311 return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Any clue? Many thanks.

Comment: See if this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400867/pandas-read-csv-from-url

Comment: The end of stacktrace error is:

`HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

I tried to add a header to read_csv, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the `storage_options` argument:

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/pandas/plotting/alphabet_stock_data.csv"
storage_options = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
df = pd.read_csv(url, storage_options=storage_options)
```

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68816828/5304366

Answer (score 1):

I like to use requests with pandas.

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd
import requests


def get_data() -> pd.DataFrame:
    url = "https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/pandas/plotting/alphabet_stock_data.csv"

    with requests.Session() as request:
        response = request.get(url)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(response.raise_for_status())

    return pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.text), sep=",")


print(get_data())
```

Comment: A great alternative. Thank you.